# Issue with position:absolute;

Tags: css, position, css-position

so this is what is happening, as you can see from the image below The browser screen size is making the woman cover things or move as I call it.

Here is my code

```
img#woman{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    display:block;
    right:55%;
    z-index: 900;
}
#homearea{
    display:block;
    height:750px;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdNi7.jpg[image: Screen Suze of Woman]

I need to woman to stay in one spot she should look like this

[image: what she should look like]

Comment: show your markup for better understanding & better results....

Comment: Any luck with any of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is without seeing your HTML:

Try setting the position on the containing div (#homearea?) to relative and then changing the directional values for the image to be relative to the top-left of the containing div.

In other words, try something like this:

```
img#woman{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    display:block;
    left:-30px;
    z-index: 900;
}
#homearea{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:750px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you may be you used this images in background as like this

Define your Homearea id position relative and woman id give position absolute and give to background images and set to left right top bottom according to your layout

As like this

**Css**

```
#homearea{
 position:relative;

}

#woman{
width:xxx; // width of your images
height:xx; // height of your images
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    right:55%;
    z-index: 900;
background:url('../../xxx.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="homearea">
    <div id="woman"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define **postion:relative;** to your **Parent Div** and **position:absolute;** to your **Child Div** hope this will work......

```
 img#woman{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    display:block;
    right:55%;
    z-index: 900;
}
#homearea{
    height:750px;
    position:relative; 
}
```